# Particles.js — modify on frame-change

Tags: javascript, particles

Apologies for my complete lack of javascript intuition, but I was wondering if it is possible to change properties of a [`particles.js`](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js) object dynamically:

I'm using `jQuery` to detect when a user moves a slider on the screen (successfully). However, I was wondering how to apply these slider-value changes to the `particles.js` canvas I have in the background.

I.e. Move the slider across, and the particles get larger.

However, I'm not sure how to update the `particles.js` — is anyone familiar with a callback or animation loop function that I can drop my property changes into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/issues/9) on this subject.
But you can change it manually by accessing the radius property of each particle:

```
pJS.particles.array.forEach(function(p) { 
    p.radius = p.radius * sliderValue; // change by a factor
    p.radius = sliderValue; // change to a single size
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just looked at the open issue (thanks for the spot), but your solution works *perfectly*! Amazing :)