# How to change radius in particles.js

Tags: javascript, particles.js

I don't know how to reduce the outer radius of the cursor in particles.js. How do I do that? I searched before btw...

Comment: On the demo page https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/ it's in interactivity - modes - repulse - distance.

Answer (score 0):

**This is an example that alters the radius of the particles.**

```
window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array.forEach(function(p) { 
  p.radius = 11; // change to a single size
});
```

This solution was provided on this other post [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738469/particles-js-modify-on-frame-change) thanks to @eladcon user

You can go to this [pen](https://codepen.io/codemajic/pen/oJoYVG) to see where is this lines of code been used and how it changes.